# Cordova plugin for google map distance matrix service

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to develop an android application in `cordova`. It have to implement some google map functionalities like `distance matrix service` and `direction service`. But I haven't find any plugin for these functions. I'm using [cordova-plugin-googlemaps](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps) for initializing google map.

I tried to do this in javascript itself but it have [ReferenceError: google is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449871/google-maps-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-in-cordova-android-applicatio?noredirect=1#comment103331346_58449871) and I have pushed the specific file to [github](https://github.com/jzlinn/public-demo/blob/master/maps.js)

> Is there any other plugins have these supports ??
>
> Or is it possible to write native android code to do this functionality that works in cordova application (like  bridging kind of things) ??

**p.s: I have no previous experience in mobile app development and Java related things**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the folks from [these](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/928) [multiple](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2699) [issues](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/1488) state, this plugin does not have support for the Directions and Distance Matrix services at this time, but you can implement them through the [JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/services) or through HTTP [Web Services](https://developers.google.com/maps/web-services/client-library).

Hope this helps point you in the right direction!